# Spark unable to find "spark-version-info.properties" when run from ammonite script

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ammonite

I have an ammonite script which creates a spark context:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/amm

import ammonite.ops._

import $ivy.`org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.0.1`

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

@main
def main(): Unit = {
  val sc =  new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Demo"))
}
```

When I run this script, it throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error while locating file spark-version-info.properties
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
```

The script isn't being run from the spark installation directory and doesn't have any knowledge of it or the resources where this version information is packaged - it only knows about the ivy dependencies. So perhaps the issue is that this resource information isn't on the classpath in the ivy dependencies. I have seen other spark "standalone scripts" so I was hoping I could do the same here.

---

I poked around a bit to try and understand what was happening. I was hoping I could programmatically hack some build information into the system properties at runtime.

The source of the exception comes from [package.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/package.scala) in the spark library. The relevant bits of code are

```
val resourceStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.
  getResourceAsStream("spark-version-info.properties")

try {
  val unknownProp = "<unknown>"
  val props = new Properties()
  props.load(resourceStream) <--- causing a NPE?
  (
    props.getProperty("version", unknownProp),
    // Load some other properties
  )
} catch {
  case npe: NullPointerException =>
    throw new SparkException("Error while locating file spark-version-info.properties", npe)
```

It seems that the implicit assumption is that `props.load` will fail with a NPE if the version information can't be found in the resources. (That's not so clear to the reader!)

The NPE itself looks like it's coming from this code in `java.util.Properties.java`:

```
class LineReader {
    public LineReader(InputStream inStream) {
        this.inStream = inStream;
        inByteBuf = new byte[8192];
    }

    ...
    InputStream inStream;
    Reader reader;

    int readLine() throws IOException {
      ...
      inLimit = (inStream==null)?reader.read(inCharBuf)
                                :inStream.read(inByteBuf);
```

The `LineReader` is constructed with a null `InputStream` which the class internally interprets as meaning that the `reader` is non-null and should be used instead - but it's also `null`. (Is this kind of stuff really in the standard library? Seems very unsafe...)

---

From looking at the `bin/spark-shell` that comes with spark, it adds `-Dscala.usejavacp=true` when it launches `spark-submit`. Is this the right direction?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following seems to work on 2.11 with 1.0.1 version but not experimental.

Could be just better implemented on Spark 2.2

```
#!/usr/local/bin/amm

import ammonite.ops._
import $ivy.`org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0` 
import $ivy.`org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.2.0`
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

@main
def main(): Unit = {
    val sc =  new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Demo"))
}
```

or more expanded answer:

```
@main
def main(): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("testings")
      .master("local")
      .config("configuration key", "configuration value")
      .getOrCreate 
  val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
  val tdf2 = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").option("header", true).csv("./tst.dat")
  tdf2.show()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ran your script but hit the dreaded: "NoSuchMethodError ...ArrayOps" which is usually a binary compatibility problem. That's using both scala 2.12.3 and scala 2.11.8 with java 1.8.0_25 and ammonite 1.0.1 (https://git.io/v7cx7). Are you able to list the versions of the tools you're using? I also tried deleting the `~/.ammonite/cache` but still get the same error.

Comment: ~$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144).
~$ amm
Loading...
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 1.0.1
(Scala 2.11.11 Java 1.8.0_144)
 uname -r
4.4.0-91-generic
Lubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit. I would say nuke:
$ rm -rf ~/.coursier/cache/v1/https/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots
if that don't work
$mv ~/.ivy2 ~/.ivy2.bak

Comment: Thanks @quantt. I realised that the scala version defined by SCALA_HOME wasn't used by ammonite and it in fact uses its own version of scala. Also I realised that even the older ammonite installers seem to use the most recent version of ammonite, but older versions of scala. When I used amm version https://git.io/v5Tcm the script worked. My output is: "Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 1.0.2
(Scala 2.11.11 Java 1.8.0_25)" which is actually a newer ammonite to what I first tried, but with an older scala. So currently this is a solution for scala 2.11 but not 2.12.

Comment: :) 1st line of my line: Following seems to work on 2.11 with 1.0.1 version but not experimental.
I should have said scala 2.11